# Create custom home page for each user in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, wss

We are using WSS 3.0 with Windows server 2003 Std R2 for our office intranet. Right now every AD user logs on to the WSS site with same default page. I would like to know if it's possible to create custom home page per user for my default site.

I really appreciate any reply/thoughs...

Thanks,
Hemal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Each user should choose "personalize this page"  from the sign in and edit the webparts as they like.

Comment: I can only see the "Personalize this page" Sign in option for administrators but for my other domain users, I can't see that option. Does anyone know how to enable this option from "Sign In" page?

Thank you in advance....

Comment: it's likely a problem with the permissions Go to the top level of your team site, then go to site permissions. Then Edit Permission Levels. make sure everyone has the "manage personal views" permission, (and probably the other 2 permission under manage personal views)

Comment: Thank you Jim.. It worked out great. Thank you for your help and sorry to acknowledge it....